# Adding commands for Contextmenu inside ListViewItem Style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listviewitem

I am searching for a solution for the ContextMenu's commands defined under ListViewItem style. Binding was successful when I defined and bind the commands inside ContextMenu within ListView.

I used viewModel class file to define the commands ex: ExecuteClone, CanExecuteClone which i am trying to bind it with ContextMenu menu items using Command Binding.

```
 <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
            </ContextMenu>
 </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

But when i change the ContextMenu from ListView to ListViewItem, it doesn't hit the ViewModel command.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Clone" Command="{Binding CloneCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It needs to hit the ViewModel AddCommand, CloneCommand which are DelegateCommand actions defined under ViewModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with some trials, anyways thanks for the help.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Clone" Command="{Binding CloneCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListViewItems have a different DataContext than the ListView. Every ListViewItem has its DataContext set to one of the items in your ItemsSource collection, so this is why the binding doesn't work. If you want to bind the commands to the ListView's DataContext, you can do it like that:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.AddCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
```

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the response. But it is not working for me. I tried to put DataContext for ContextMenu also. Either options doesn't work.